# What is the name of this shot used in King Arthur?

Tags: film-techniques, king-arthur-2004

Link is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gCHm.jpg

What is the name of this shot used in King Arthur (2004)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An **Aerial Fly-by** shot.

Recently very common with the advent of cheap photography drones. More expensive in the past due to needing a helicopter.